# Why can't I pass global Variables as parameters in function declaration

Tags: c++, function

Why can't I define a variable globally and then pass that to function so that I can use that variable at multiple places? I tried doing this in the below code but the compiler is throwing error.

```
#inclued <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

int add(int a, int b){
    int c = a+b;
    return c;
}

int main(){
    int c = add(5,6);
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Please don't post your code as image because images of code is hard to use. Please post your code **as text** directly in your question.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Your global variables are *shadowing* the function arguments to `add`. This is warning at least, and an error if your compiler is configured as such.

Comment: Moreover, in the function's definition, the arguments types are missing. This is invalid.

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with the scope of your variables, and you would encounter the same problem if you didn't have any global variables with those names. The compiler complains because you don't know the fundamentals about defining and using functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare global variables you don't need declare again in the functions,instead you can use directly

```
 int a = 0;
 int b = 0;
 int add(){
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
 }
```

if you really want to declare functions with params then you don't need global variables because the function will use your param not your global variable.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you should not post your code as an image, you can follow the below link to know more about this.

[Why can't I pass global Variables as parameters in function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688872/why-cant-i-pass-global-variables-as-parameters-in-function-declaration).

In your code, you have declared both `a` and `b` as a global variable. But in your add function,  `a` and `b` are both completely new variables in their local space. That is why changing value in their local space won't make any impact on those global variables.